# understanding 3>>2 and -3>>2 results in Java

Tags: java

When I running the code:

```
public class OperateDemo18{
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 3 ; // 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
    int y = -3 ;    // 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
    System.out.println(x>>2) ;    
    System.out.println(y>>2) ;    
   }
};
```

I get output as:

```
x>>2 is 0
y>>2 is -1
```

As my understanding, since `int x = 3`, `x>>2` is equal to `(3/2)/2` which is `0.75`, to integer, `x>>2` is `0`.

But I don't understand why for `int y = -3`, `y>>2` is `-1`. Could anyone please explain it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> As my understanding, since int x = 3, x>>2 is equal to (3/2)/2 which is 0.75, to integer, x>>2 is 0.

That's not entirely true; `>>` is a bitshift operation, *nothing else*. The effect on positive integers is division by powers of two, yes. But for unsigned integers, it's not:

You conveniently supplied the binary form of `y == -3` yourself:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
```

let's bitshift that right by two!

```
y   == 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
y>>2== xx111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Now, what do you fill in for `x`?

Java, like most reasonable languages, sign-extends, ie. it uses the original highest (leftmost) bit:

```
y   == 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
y>>2== 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

It isn't hard to see that this is the "biggest" negative integer (remember, negative integers are represented as "two's complement"!), i.e. `-1`.

Comment: Thank you, it's really helpful!

Answer (score 2):

`>>` operator shifts the bits from left to right, and enters the most-significant (leftmost) bit from the left, therefore in case of:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000011
```

it becomes:

```
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

and in case of:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111101
```

it becomes:

```
11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand it now.